# error occurs. Process returned (0xC0000005)

Tags: c, switch-statement, avl-tree

I'm trying to build and run the following code on code blocks(c language), but it crashes and returns the (0xC0000005) error. OMG.
I'm beginner, now. So, i can't understand why this happen.
I want to make AVL TREE while typing in cmd.
So, i use switch case, but when i add this code, the error occur.
i know this error occur when i use unallocated memory in code.
but i don't know that now.
Any kind of help is appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *left, *right;
    int height;
};

int max(int a, int b);

int height(struct node *node)
{
    if (node == NULL)
        return 0;
    return node -> height;
}

int max(int a, int b)
{
    return (a > b)? a : b;
}

struct node* newNode(int item)
{
    struct node* temp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp->data = item;
    temp->left = temp->right = NULL;
    temp->height = 1;
    return temp;
}

struct node *RRotate(struct node *y)
{
    struct node *x = y->left;
    struct node *T2 = x->right;

    x->right = y;
    y->left = T2;

    y->height = max(height(y->left), height(y->right))+1;
    x->height = max(height(x->left), height(x->right))+1;

    return x;
};

struct node *LRotate(struct node *x)
{
    struct node *y = x->right;
    struct node *T2 = y->left;

    y->left = x;
    x->right = T2;

    x->height = max(height(x->left), height(x->right))+1;
    y->height = max(height(y->left), height(y->right))+1;

    return y;
};

int makeBalance(struct node *node)
{
    if (node = NULL)
        return 0;
    return height(node->left) - height(node->right);
}

struct node* insert(struct node *root, int data)
{

    if (root == NULL)
        return newNode(data);

    if (data < root->data)
        root->left = insert(root->left, data);
    else if (data > root->data)
        root->right = insert(root->right, data);
    else
        return root;


    root->height = 1 + max(height(root->left), height(root->right));

    int balance = makeBalance(root);

    if(balance < -1 && data > root->right->data)
        return LRotate(root);
    if(balance > 1 && data < root->left->data)
        return RRotate(root);
    if(balance > 1 && data>root->left->data)
    {
        root->left = LRotate(root->left);
        return RRotate(root);
    }
    if(balance < -1 && data < root->right->data)
    {
        root->right = RRotate(root->right);
        return LRotate(root);
    }

    return root;
}

struct node* minV(struct node *root) {
  struct node *current = root;

  while (current && current->left != NULL)
    current = current->left;

  return current;
}

struct node* deleteN(struct node *root, int data) {
    if(root=NULL)
        return root;
    if(data<root->data)
        root->left = deleteN(root->left, data);
    else if(data>root->data)
        root->right = deleteN(root->right, data);
    else{
        if((root->left==NULL)||(root->right==NULL))
        {
            struct node *temp = root->left ? root->left : root->right;

            if(temp == NULL){
                temp = root;
                root = NULL;
            }
            else
                *root = *temp;
            free(temp);
        }
        else{
            struct node *temp = minV(root->right);
            root->data = temp->data;
            root->right = deleteN(root->right, temp->data);
        }
    }

    if(root == NULL)
        return root;

    root->height = 1+max(height(root->left), height(root->right));

    int balance = makeBalance(root);
    if(balance > 1 && makeBalance(root->left)>=0)
        return RRotate(root);
    if(balance > 1 && makeBalance(root->left)<0){
        root->left = LRotate(root->left);
        return RRotate(root);
    }
    if(balance <-1 && makeBalance(root->right)<=0)
        return LRotate(root);
    if(balance < -1 && makeBalance(root->right)> 0){
        root->right = RRotate(root->right);
        return LRotate(root);
    }

    return root;


}

struct node* search(struct node *root, int data)
{
    if(root = NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    else if(data == root->data)
    {
        return root;
    }
    else if(data < root->data)
    {
        search(root->left, data);
    }
    else
    {
        search(root->right, data);
    }
}

void preorder(struct node *root)
{
    if(root!=NULL)
    {
        printf(root->data);
        preorder(root->left);
        preorder(root->right);
    }
}

int main()
{
    struct node *root;
    int number;
    int number2;
    int number3;
    bool bOnLoop = true;
    printf("Insert root number:");
    scanf("%d", &number);
    root = newNode(number);
    while(bOnLoop)
    {
        printf("1.Insert 2.Delete 3.Search 4.Preorder 5.End\n");
        printf("Select Mode Number:");
        scanf("%d", &number3);
        switch(number3){
        case 1:
            printf("Insert Number:");
            scanf("%d", &number2);
            insert(root, number2);
            break;
        case 2:
            printf("Insert Number:");
            scanf("%d", &number2);
            deleteN(root, number2);
            break;
        case 3:
            printf("Insert Number:");
            scanf("%d", &number2);
            search(root, number2);
            break;
        case 4:
            printf("Insert Number:");
            scanf("%d", &number2);
            preorder(root);
            break;
        case 5:
            bOnLoop = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: This is a great opportunity to learn how to use a debugger...

Comment: Running your program through [an online compiler](https://godbolt.org/z/oKbYsrrrE) reveals about 10 warnings. You'll want to heed and fix those first. Make sure to run your compiler at the highest warning level (e.g. `-Wall`).

Comment: [What compiler options are recommended for beginners learning C?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/282565)

Comment: Red flags for `if (node = NULL) return 0;` and `if(root=NULL) return root;` Because you *assigned* a `NULL` value, the boolean expression always evaluates to `false` and so you continue to dereference the `NULL` pointer regardless of its original value.

Comment: thank you. i understand

Answer (score 0):

The compiler showed that there were some syntax error:

```
gcc -Wall -Wpedantic -g ./*.c
```

Compiler Warnings:

```sh
./main.c:46:2: warning: ISO C does not allow extra ‘;’ outside of a function [-Wpedantic]
   46 | };
      |  ^
./main.c:60:2: warning: ISO C does not allow extra ‘;’ outside of a function [-Wpedantic]
   60 | };
      |  ^
./main.c: In function ‘makeBalance’:
./main.c:64:9: warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value [-Wparentheses]
   64 |     if (node = NULL)
      |         ^~~~
./main.c: In function ‘deleteN’:
./main.c:115:8: warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value [-Wparentheses]
  115 |     if(root=NULL)
      |        ^~~~
./main.c: In function ‘search’:
./main.c:167:8: warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value [-Wparentheses]
  167 |     if(root = NULL)
      |        ^~~~
./main.c: In function ‘preorder’:
./main.c:189:20: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘printf’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
  189 |         printf(root->data);
      |                ~~~~^~~~~~
      |                    |
      |                    int
In file included from ./main.c:1:
/usr/include/stdio.h:332:43: note: expected ‘const char * restrict’ but argument is of type ‘int’
  332 | extern int printf (const char *__restrict __format, ...);
      |                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~
./main.c:189:9: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Wformat-security]
  189 |         printf(root->data);
      |         ^~~~~~
./main.c: In function ‘search’:
./main.c:183:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
  183 | }
      | ^

Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.

> Executing task: gcc -Wall -Wpedantic -g ./*.c <

./main.c:47:2: warning: ISO C does not allow extra ‘;’ outside of a function [-Wpedantic]
   47 | };
      |  ^
./main.c:61:2: warning: ISO C does not allow extra ‘;’ outside of a function [-Wpedantic]
   61 | };
      |  ^
./main.c: In function ‘makeBalance’:
./main.c:65:9: warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value [-Wparentheses]
   65 |     if (node = NULL)
      |         ^~~~
./main.c: In function ‘deleteN’:
./main.c:117:9: warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value [-Wparentheses]
  117 |     if (root = NULL)
      |         ^~~~
./main.c: In function ‘search’:
./main.c:172:9: warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value [-Wparentheses]
  172 |     if (root = NULL)
      |         ^~~~
./main.c: In function ‘preorder’:
./main.c:194:20: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘printf’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
  194 |         printf(root->data);
      |                ~~~~^~~~~~
      |                    |
      |                    int
In file included from ./main.c:1:
/usr/include/stdio.h:332:43: note: expected ‘const char * restrict’ but argument is of type ‘int’
  332 | extern int printf (const char *__restrict __format, ...);
      |                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~
./main.c:194:9: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Wformat-security]
  194 |         printf(root->data);
      |         ^~~~~~
./main.c: In function ‘search’:
./main.c:188:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
  188 | }
      | ^
```

I fixed these errors.
Especially make sure that you use `==` for comparison in `if` conditions and NOT a single `=`. You where setting one of the arguments to `NULL` in a `if` condition by writing `if (node = NULL)`. After fixing the compiler warnings I was able to successful compile and run the program:

```sh
$ a.out

Insert root number:5
1.Insert 2.Delete 3.Search 4.Preorder 5.End
Select Mode Number:1
Insert Number:10
1.Insert 2.Delete 3.Search 4.Preorder 5.End
Select Mode Number:5

$
```

Here is my version of your program:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *left, *right;
    int height;
};

int max(int a, int b);

int height(struct node *node)
{
    if (node == NULL)
        return 0;
    return node->height;
}

int max(int a, int b)
{
    return (a > b) ? a : b;
}

struct node *newNode(int item)
{
    struct node *temp = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp->data = item;
    temp->left = temp->right = NULL;
    temp->height = 1;
    return temp;
}

struct node *RRotate(struct node *y)
{
    struct node *x = y->left;
    struct node *T2 = x->right;

    x->right = y;
    y->left = T2;

    y->height = max(height(y->left), height(y->right)) + 1;
    x->height = max(height(x->left), height(x->right)) + 1;

    return x;
}

struct node *LRotate(struct node *x)
{
    struct node *y = x->right;
    struct node *T2 = y->left;

    y->left = x;
    x->right = T2;

    x->height = max(height(x->left), height(x->right)) + 1;
    y->height = max(height(y->left), height(y->right)) + 1;

    return y;
}

int makeBalance(struct node *node)
{
    if (node == NULL)
        return 0;
    return height(node->left) - height(node->right);
}

struct node *insert(struct node *root, int data)
{

    if (root == NULL)
        return newNode(data);

    if (data < root->data)
        root->left = insert(root->left, data);
    else if (data > root->data)
        root->right = insert(root->right, data);
    else
        return root;

    root->height = 1 + max(height(root->left), height(root->right));

    int balance = makeBalance(root);

    if (balance < -1 && data > root->right->data)
        return LRotate(root);
    if (balance > 1 && data < root->left->data)
        return RRotate(root);
    if (balance > 1 && data > root->left->data)
    {
        root->left = LRotate(root->left);
        return RRotate(root);
    }
    if (balance < -1 && data < root->right->data)
    {
        root->right = RRotate(root->right);
        return LRotate(root);
    }

    return root;
}

struct node *minV(struct node *root)
{
    struct node *current = root;

    while (current && current->left != NULL)
        current = current->left;

    return current;
}

struct node *deleteN(struct node *root, int data)
{
    if (root == NULL)
        return root;
    if (data < root->data)
        root->left = deleteN(root->left, data);
    else if (data > root->data)
        root->right = deleteN(root->right, data);
    else
    {
        if ((root->left == NULL) || (root->right == NULL))
        {
            struct node *temp = root->left ? root->left : root->right;

            if (temp == NULL)
            {
                temp = root;
                root = NULL;
            }
            else
                *root = *temp;
            free(temp);
        }
        else
        {
            struct node *temp = minV(root->right);
            root->data = temp->data;
            root->right = deleteN(root->right, temp->data);
        }
    }

    if (root == NULL)
        return root;

    root->height = 1 + max(height(root->left), height(root->right));

    int balance = makeBalance(root);
    if (balance > 1 && makeBalance(root->left) >= 0)
        return RRotate(root);
    if (balance > 1 && makeBalance(root->left) < 0)
    {
        root->left = LRotate(root->left);
        return RRotate(root);
    }
    if (balance < -1 && makeBalance(root->right) <= 0)
        return LRotate(root);
    if (balance < -1 && makeBalance(root->right) > 0)
    {
        root->right = RRotate(root->right);
        return LRotate(root);
    }

    return root;
}

struct node *search(struct node *root, int data)
{
    if (root == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    else if (data == root->data)
    {
        return root;
    }
    else if (data < root->data)
    {
        return search(root->left, data);
    }
    else
    {
        return search(root->right, data);
    }
    return root;
}

void preorder(struct node *root)
{
    if (root != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d", root->data);
        preorder(root->left);
        preorder(root->right);
    }
}

int main()
{
    struct node *root;
    int number;
    int number2;
    int number3;
    bool bOnLoop = true;
    printf("Insert root number:");
    scanf("%d", &number);
    root = newNode(number);
    while (bOnLoop)
    {
        printf("1.Insert 2.Delete 3.Search 4.Preorder 5.End\n");
        printf("Select Mode Number:");
        scanf("%d", &number3);
        switch (number3)
        {
        case 1:
            printf("Insert Number:");
            scanf("%d", &number2);
            insert(root, number2);
            break;
        case 2:
            printf("Insert Number:");
            scanf("%d", &number2);
            deleteN(root, number2);
            break;
        case 3:
            printf("Insert Number:");
            scanf("%d", &number2);
            search(root, number2);
            break;
        case 4:
            printf("Insert Number:");
            scanf("%d", &number2);
            preorder(root);
            break;
        case 5:
            bOnLoop = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you. i understand

Comment: You are welcome. If this information helps you with question, could you please mark it as the answer?